# Java SWT clear table headers

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I'm working on a SWT GUI and I'm trying to create a button that on press clear all table data and the headers.

```
table.removeAll();
```

This command don't work well because it's removing only the data inside and I need to remove the table headers too.

Is there a solution?

***EDIT:*** after the code to clear the header worked, if I try to add new file with data, the header go to the next point. why if it blank? (the ArrayLists that contains the header names cleared too).

First image is when first file uploaded, after click on "Start" button the data shown on table:
[image]

Second image is after the table cleared all data by pressing on another button:
[image]

Third image is after uploading new file and press "Start" button:
[image]

***EDIT:*** Headers Set

```
            tableConfigurationSystemColumnTools.add("Parameter Name");
            for (String str : tableSystemColumn) {
                String[] a = str.split("PCM");
                tableConfigurationSystemColumnTools.add(a[0].trim());
            }
                for (int loopIndexSystemColumnTools = 0; 
                loopIndexSystemColumnTools < tableConfigurationSystemColumnTools.size(); loopIndexSystemColumnTools++) {
                TableColumn column = new TableColumn(tableConfigurationSystem, SWT.NULL);
                column.setWidth(100);
                column.setText(tableConfigurationSystemColumnTools.get(loopIndexSystemColumnTools));
              }
              for (int loopIndexSystemColumnTools = 0; loopIndexSystemColumnTools < tableConfigurationSystemColumnTools.size(); loopIndexSystemColumnTools++) {
                  tableConfigurationSystem.getColumn(loopIndexSystemColumnTools).pack();
              }
```

***EDIT:*** I've founded the answer, look at my comment.

Comment: You will have to set the text of each `TableColumn` to blank.

Comment: @greg-449 please see the EDIT

Comment: I don't understand the edit. You will need to set the text of  each `TableColumn` back to want you want.

Comment: I'm uploading file, press "start" button, then the data from the text file shown on table. when I press "clear" the table data removed and the columns now, but here is one problem.. when I upload new file then data shown well but the headers move to next index where it stopped from last file.

Comment: You will have to show us the code you are using to set the headers again.

Comment: edited, please look.

Comment: You must **not** create any new TableColumns just use the same loop as in the answer but set the text to non-blank.

Comment: edited again, please look.

Comment: Showing us odd bits of code is no good, show a proper [mcve]. But you still appear the be creating new TableColumns multiple times - you must only do that when the table is created.

Comment: sorry, but I just cant understand my error... :(

Answer (score 2):

```
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        table.removeAll();
        TableColumn[] columns = table.getColumns();
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            columns[i].setText("");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not understanding your EDIT notes. Please paste your entire code ( or if there is confidential data, create mock code and paste). It helps us to debug.

Comment: I am not getting any meaning out of your code. As said could you please provide full compiling code, where you are facing issues. That will help us to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I founded the answer - in the "for" loop that creating TableColumn, I'v added "index":

```
TableColumn column = new TableColumn(tableConfigurationSystem, SWT.NONE, loopIndexSystemColumnTools);
```

this is working.

Thank you guys.